# C#, it failed at Script compilation error: Cannot declare namespace in script code

Tags: c#

I found this code I want to run in a script, but I have this error:

> Script compilation error: **Cannot declare namespace in script code**

I want to finish a function that to send a email by C#

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace WindowsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sina.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply_test@sina.com");
                mail.To.Add("blog_dev@example.com");
                mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
                mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from SINA";

                SmtpServer.Port = 25;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hello", "world");
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);
                MessageBox.Show("mail Send");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: That's an unusual error message, what are you trying to compile it with?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "when I run the query"? You've shown a Windows Forms application... I don't see any sign of a C# script or a query. Please give us more context - it may well be that you're trying to use C# in a context where this kind of code is inappropriate.

Comment: Are you trying to run this with csi? rosyln?

Comment: That code compiles and runs just fine on Visual Studio 17 as a C# Windows Forms project.

Comment: It seems you run `scriptcs` yourself. Please consider developing in a real IDE instead of using Notepad and compiling yourself. An IDE has many advantages...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for your helping on this blog.
I just have figured out on my own, just use the pure functional code, works well.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.sina.com");

mail.From = new MailAddress("noreply_test@sina.com");
mail.To.Add("blog_dev@example.com");
mail.Subject = "Test Mail";
mail.Body = "This is for testing SMTP mail from SINA";

SmtpServer.Port = 25;
SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("hello", "world");
SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

Comment: I ran into the same problem today. It took hours, but I finally got it to work. Did you ever happen to figure out why it doesn't work with the class & namespace?